# Authenticator cant resolve code from password

Tags: one-time-password, freeradius, google-authenticator

I am trying to implement 2FA for L2TP VPN but problem is that google authenticator cant resolve code from password (pass + OTP) which is MSCHAP2, I don't wanna change it on PAP because it is not secured.

Is there any way to sent code over username (username + OTP)?